# Distribution of the sum of two dependent poisson random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, self-learning

I am self-learning undergraduate calculus-based probability. I'd like someone to verify, if my conclusion for the below exercise problem from *Intro to Probability*, Blitzstein and Hwang, 4.27 is correct.

> [BH 4.27] Let $X$ and $Y$ be $Poisson(\lambda)$ random variables and $T=X+Y$. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are *not* independent, and in fact $X = Y$. Prove or disprove the claim that $T \sim Poisson(2\lambda)$ in this scenario.

**Solution.** (My Attempt)

I cannot come up with a direct counterexample to disprove the above. However, we see that:

\begin{align*}
P(T = k) &= P(2X = k)\\
&= P(X = k/2) \\
&= e^{-\lambda}\frac{(\lambda)^{k/2}}{(k/2)!} \quad k\in\{0,2,4,\ldots\}
\end{align*}

This density is certainly different from $Poisson(2\lambda)$.

Comment: your density can't be right because $P(T=1) = 0$

Comment: @Tortar, that density I believe should only be defined for $k=0,2,4,\ldots$.

Comment: yes if you define $k=2n$ then I think you are right

Comment: anyway a direct counterexample is indeed $P(T=1) = 0$ while if $T$ would be $Poisson(2\lambda)$ it would be positive

Comment: Yup! Poisson density is positive for all points. And that would suffice.

Comment: It’s not a density but a probability mass function — that being said your answer looks correct to me — as you pointed out this only is defined over the even integers so it’s just a stretched out version of the original